# Two notions of conditional expectation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory

For a randomn variable $Y$ and an event $B$ we can define:

$$E(Y \mid B) = \frac{E(1_B\cdot Y)}{P(B)}$$ as the conditional expectation.

Now, for a sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}$ and sets $B$ in it you can also define:

$$\int_B E(X|\mathcal{B}) \, dP \; = \; \int_B X \, dP.$$

What I was wondering about is: Is the first definition somehow contained in the second one? 
I mean,  we can treat $E(Y|B)$ as a (almost sure ) constant random variable. The problem is, $B$ is not a sigma algebra and therefore I don't see whether we can interpret $E(Y|B)$ in the sense of the second definition. Are there really two disjoint disjoint definitions for a conditional expectation available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $\mathcal{B} = \{ \emptyset, B, B', \Omega\}$ and define your random variable $E(X|\mathcal{B}) = E(X|B)$ on $B$ and $E(X|\mathcal{B}) = E(X|B')$ on $B'$.

then the two formulas are equivalent: $$\int_B E(X|\mathcal{B}) \, dP = E(X | B) P(B) $$
and $$ \int_B X \, dP = E(1_B X). $$